# Socket.Io: Choose Where to Connect

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io, nodejitsu

My application is hosted on Nodejitsu and uses multiple drones/servers.

According to the [Nodejitsu documentation](https://www.nodejitsu.com/documentation/faq/#how-to-target-a-specific-drone-of-an-application-), I can target a specific drone via the http header

`'x-drone':1` where 1 is the drone number.

On client side, it looks something like this: (I think this is how it's supposed to be. I can't test it because I don't have multiple drones yet.)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path',
    headers: { 'x-drone': 1 }
});
```

Is there a way to establish a socket.io connection to a specific drone?

Right now, this is what I have on client side (but it connects to least busy drone):

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    var socket = io(); //version 1.0
```

I searched in the documentation about `io()` for options parameter but couldn't find anything.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: It's not possible. I got recommended to have multiple applications with 1 drone each instead. And each application runs on a different subdomain.